# When was block scope for variables introduced to C, and why is it still frowned upon?

Tags: c, scope, memory-usage

In light of the recent [`OBJ_obj2txt`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/lib/libssl/src/crypto/objects/obj_dat.c#OBJ_obj2txt) vulnerability in LibreSSL (which was [found during the OpenSMTPD audit, and does not affect OpenSSL](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2015/q4/87)), it came to my attention that the memory leak issue likely resulted from some [earlier code refactoring](http://cvsweb.allbsd.org/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libssl/src/crypto/objects/obj_dat.c?cvsroot=openbsd#rev1.25), where the *block scoped* variable `char *bndec` was moved out to be *function scoped* instead.

I know first-hand that there is this great resistance to *block scoped* variables within old-school projects like OpenBSD, but what other justification would there be to move the `char *bndec` declaration?

More broadly, when was block scoping introduced for variables in C?  All I could find is that it [was already part of C89](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880752/1122270).  Is that where it started, or was it also part of an earlier spec?

Comment: @cnst: Sounds like you already know the answer to your own question.  Perhaps you can provide proof for your assertion: "Frankly, I know first-hand that there is this great resistance to block scoped variables within old-school projects like OpenBSD," as there seems to be no such resistance apparent here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, but I don't know the answer; just because your answer is wrong (wasn't me who pointed it out!  But I did agree!), doesn't mean I have a better one.

Comment: Have a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/200709, especially the accepted answer: *"If your function is so long that you cannot recognize any unwanted side effects or illegal reuse of variables any more, then it is time to split it up in smaller functions - which makes an internal scope pointless."*

Comment: Why did this question attract so much attention, yet has such a low score?

Answer (score 7):

*TL;DR*: It's not an issue of block scoping, but rather a misunderstanding of how pointers should be handled.

---

Courtesy of the [vulnerability listing](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2015/q4/87) that you posted, let's take a look at the code in question.

```
489 int
490 OBJ_obj2txt(char *buf, int buf_len, const ASN1_OBJECT *a, int no_name)
491 {
...
494         char *bndec = NULL;
...
516         len = a->length;
...
519         while (len > 0) {
...
570                         bndec = BN_bn2dec(bl);
571                         if (!bndec)
572                                 goto err;
573                         i = snprintf(buf, buf_len, ".%s", bndec);
...
598         }
...
601         free(bndec);
...
609 }
```

And if we delve into the [declaration of `BN_bn2dec`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/lib/libssl/src/crypto/bn/bn_print.c) we see a comment of:

```
/* Must 'free' the returned data */
```

---

What you see as a block scoping issue, I see as a poor understanding of pointer operations as the root issue.

This [diff revision](http://cvsweb.allbsd.org/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/libssl/src/crypto/objects/obj_dat.c.diff?r1=1.24&r2=1.25&cvsroot=openbsd&f=h) shows when the `*bndec` was moved from inside the while loop to outside the while loop.  The error was also introduced at the same time when the `free(bndec)` statement was moved outside the loop.

Where `*bndec` is declared for this function is a bit irrelevant.  It can safely be defined either outside or inside the while loop.  And if memory serves correctly, the actual declaration will be moved to the top of the function by the compiler anyway.

Declaring `*bndec` inside the loop merely would have forced an error if the `free()` call remained outside of the loop.  It remains to be seen whether that error would have been sufficient to alert the programmer to the fallacy behind their refactoring logic.

Being a bit of a pessimist when it comes to most programmers and pointers, I'm going to posit that the `free` accessing an out-of-scope variable error wouldn't have helped them discover the error of their ways.  Instead, they would have taken the naive (and incorrect) solution of resolving the error by merely moving the variable declaration outside of the block. And that's why I disagree with the contention that the root cause of this is a block scoping issue.

If C happened to have garbage collection, then block scoping would have been of more value in this case.  But it doesn't, and that line of thought becomes pointless speculation.

---

Unfortunately, we don't really know *why* the refactoring programmer chose to move that `free(bndec)` statement.  All that they left via check-in comments was this:

> Clean up some of the nightmare of string and pointer arithmatic in
>   this nasty function.
>   This gets rid of the nasty tmp variables used to hold temporary strings
>   and the DECIMAL_SIZE hack. it gets rid of the rather pointless null checks
>   for buf (since the original code dereferences it before checking). It also
>   gets rid of the insane possibility this could return -1 when stuff is
>   using the return values to compute lengths All the failure cases now
>   return 0 and an empty string like the first error case in the original
>   code.

And while I respect their dedication to clean code, I'm not certain I fully agree with their removing of various checks from the code.  Having written a fair amount of C code with a fairly large team of developers, my experience is that defensive coding practices are almost always warranted.  And while a developer may not be able to justify the time expense to *add* those defensive practices, I can't say that I have ever found valid grounds to *remove* those defenses.

To delve into an equal amount of hyperbole as the refactoring programmer, I find their check-in comment to smack a little bit too much of hubris and not enough of humility.  That hubris is likely what led them to assume they "knew what they were doing" <sup>(TM)</sup> in moving the `free(bndec)` statement, and they didn't mentally walk through what that was going to do to the code.

This error was introduced with the refactoring not because of the block scoping, but because of the failure to understand how pointers operate and the failure to understand how pointers relate to memory.

---

While I think I have established why block scoping is irrelevant to this issue, I want to address what you see as `"great resistance to block scoped variables within old-school projects"`.  And to my knowledge, ANSI C has always had block scoping available for variables.  Going out on a limb, I suspect K&R C also had it.

Keep in mind that C is not a gentle language for the naive or the initiate.  It was created in order to provide an additional layer of abstraction over `B` and assembly level programming.  Programmers writing in C were still expected to have an understanding of the underlying assembler that was being generated.  For example, variables are not automatically initialized, and many a programmer has been burned by that lack of initialization.  C expects the programmer to understand what that variable declaration maps to in memory.  C also has more than its fair share of unwritten style rules that are considered to be "good form."

Moving all variable declarations is one of those unwritten style rules, and the pragmatic reason goes back to the lack of automatic initialization.  Disciplined C programmers declared all of their variables at the beginning of the function so they could make a quick visual scan to verify that all declared variables had been initialized.  It's an easy way to make sure that a common mistake (e.g. lack of initialization) has been avoided.

Comment: That's the danger with functions that allocate code and make the caller responsible for freeing it. IMO the better solution would have been to let the caller pass in a buffer and its size to get filled with the hex of the bignum.

Comment: @ratchetfreak - I fully agree.  The existing function structuring is almost a text-book perfect case for creating memory leaks.  Touching upon that aspect though would have taken the answer too far out of scope.  :-)

Comment: What's more telling is that in the definition in the [header file](http://bxr.su/raw/OpenBSD/lib/libssl/src/crypto/bn/bn.h) (where a go to definition would bring you) there is no mention of needing to free the returned buffer of `BN_bn2dec`. You need to grep the folder to see that it mallocs the returned buffer.

Comment: "And if memory serves correctly, the actual declaration will be moved to the top of the function by the compiler anyway.": At least this is what gcc does (just checked it with a small example): variables declared in a block are allocated at the beginning of the function along with the other variables.

Comment: Whilst you do provide some interesting commentary, no, I don't agree that you've "established why block scoping is irrelevant".  This code in `obj_dat.c` must compile without warnings `CFLAGS+= -Wall -Wundef -Werror` as per http://bxr.su/o/lib/libcrypto/crypto/Makefile, and I'm pretty sure that even without such CFLAGS, the lexical processor of gcc3 would always give out an error (not and a warning) of an undefined variable due to a `free` reference out of scope like that; as such, the error would simply not have been possible had block scoping been adhered to!

Comment: @Giorgio, but you're talking about the final compiled low-level assembly / machine code code, right?  Because I'm pretty sure that at the higher level, even if such optimisation is done at the final stage (and I'm sure you're correct and it is), an undefined variable would still have to be reported as an unrecoverable error should there have been an attempt to free a block scope variable outside of the block it was defined in.

Comment: @cnst block scoping is irrelevant because the naive solution resolving the error would have been to simply move the pointer declaration outside of the block.  You're assuming that the programmer making the change would have seen the error and said "Oh, I'm an idiot, I just created a memory leak!"  My experience with developers making changes like the one shown in the diff is that they _would not_ have understood what they were doing and taken the naive solution instead.  The problem is in moving the `free`, and there was no grounds to do so.

Comment: "It's an easy way to make sure that a common mistake (e.g. lack of initialization) has been avoided." I would somewhat agree with you if there is a real need for compatibility with old compilers. In modern versions of C a much better way to ensure that is to declare the variable where it is first assigned.

Comment: @cnt: Yes. It is probably an optimization to avoid allocating variables on the stack each time you enter a block and releasing them on exit. On the other hand one could optimize on memory consumption and only allocate them when entering a block (I am thinking of alternative paths in an if-statement). I have not checked if you can use a variable outside the block it is declared in, but I would expect you cannot.

Comment: @PeterGreen: I try to avoid declaring a variable in the middle of a block. I prefer the structure <declare and set variables> <compute something and return>, a bit like writing a `let*` in Lisp or a `let` in Haskell.

Comment: @GlenH7, I think you're still ignoring the root cause and the fact that both the declaration and the free was moved outside of the loop in a single commit.  What this likely means is that, being an old-school programmer that the guy who committing this is, he first decided to move the declaration outside of the block, and only then moved the *free()* to follow (perhaps, in fact, due to a warning).  And the reason this was not spotted by two reviewers was, in fact, due to this stigma that's unfairly attached to block scope declarations.

Comment: @Giorgio, yes, I guess it was moved outside of the block on the grounds of a misguided optimisation; but then this contradicts our earlier finding in the comments to this very answer that resulting machine code declares all variables at the start of the function anyways; so, such optimisation in the higher-level presentation of the code merely acts as way to reduce clarity and introduce bugs that the compiler wouldn't be able to warn one about.

Comment: @cnt: In the generated gcc machine code I only observed that, upon entering a function, the stack pointer is modified to allocate all local variable, both those declared at the beginning of the function and those declare inside a block. This I call allocation. I am not sure what you mean by **declaring** local variables in assembly (I am no assembly expert anyway).

Answer (score 6):

In the [C Reference Manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf) that came with 6th Edition Unix (May 1975, second volume entitled "Documents for Use With the Unix Time-sharing System") the only compound statement allowed to contain variable declarations is the *function-statement*:

> *function-body*: *type-decl-list* *function-statement*
>
> *function-statement*: { *declaration-list<sub>opt</sub>* *statement-list* }

In the first edition of K&R ("The C Programming Language", 1978) you can read:

> Declarations of variables (including initializations) may follow the left brace that introduces any compound statement, not just the one that begins a function

This specification is a hint that block scoped variables was probably a recent, not well known feature (1978).

See also [Dennis M. Ritchie's page](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's originally there in the first place. The {} are not just part of control structure syntax or function definitions, but they also define a compound statement (block).

It's mentioned in this [page](http://odl.sysworks.biz/disk$vaxdocsep953/decw$book/d33vaa11.p63.decw$book): "You can use a block wherever the grammar of PDP-11 C requires a single statement."

So, the compiler did extra work when dealing with them, it's not just used to know where does a block start and end.

**Edit to clarify context**

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#Early_developments), "The development of C started in 1972 on the PDP-11 Unix system".

Comment: This seems interesting, but it's not really an answer at all -- how does your information compare to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/300274/89124, for example?  You cite no year, no context (sorry, I don't happen to be a PDP-11 expert) -- this ain't an answer at all.

Comment: sorry, I'll clarify the context

Comment: That's only a bit better -- aren't you now claiming that it wasn't introduced to C before C itself was created? :-)

Comment: I only try to answer when block scope was introduced (it wasn't) and I don't think it's bad. In fact, C++ does rather similar thing with allowing declaration in 'for' loop.

Comment: declaration within the `for` loop is legal in C99, too; as for your answer, no, you're not answering when it was introduced, because you never attempt to establish the last-modified date for the quote or document you reference; for all we know, PDP-11 C has been supported and updated for years, and the document you reference might as well be from 1999!

Comment: Although it's possible for block scoping to be added later on to support something in the machine, I believe the other way around is more likely, i.e. it's created because that's how the machine works. It's also less likely for the hardware to change something fundamental as jumping into subroutines, that's why I think PDP-11 gives all the context you need. It's like if someone asks when protected mode was introduced in an OS for PC, I would just point to intel 80286.

Comment: But Intel 80286 is hardware of specific version and release date; what you're referring to is software without any explicit version nor release date -- that's the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

This is going back 25 years, but I can remember the limits of screens where you could only see 20-22 lines of code on the screen at one go (due to terminal screen size to the Unix main frame) and it was very easy to have a function variable and a block variable with the same name and not realise it.  gcc brought in a --shadow flag to warn about this, but not all compilers had an equivalent.

Another issue was with code readability.

```
int j;
for(j=1;j<10;j++)
{
    int i=5;
    i++;
    printf("i=%i\n",i); 
}
```

Many developers at the time seemed to read this loop as setting i=5 every time around the loop, and not just set when the variable was created. Having

```
static int i=5;
```

declared within a loop would have caused no end of confusion.

Comment: Ugh... `{ int i=5` *is* setting the variable to 5 every single loop.  But, yes, `static int` within a block is indeed confusing.  I've blogged about it a few years ago -- http://cnst.livejournal.com/30259.html.